# object creation for javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am using dhtmlgoodies drag and drop script.i have to addsource for dynamically created elements using element id..if i pass id value its taking as a string..

```
var dragDropObj = new DHTMLgoodies_dragDrop();
dragDropObj.addSource('box320',true,true,true,false,'onDragFunction');
dragDropObj.addSource('box314',true,true,true,false,'onDragFunction');
```

box320,box314 are element id's..i have to pass element id dynamically.i have used

```
<div  class="dragableBox" ondrag="add1(this.id)"  id="<%=rs_list_task.getString("task_id")%>" >
function add1(id)
{
var dragDropObj = new DHTMLgoodies_dragDrop();
dragDropObj.addSource(id,true,true,true,false,'onDragFunction');
}
```

but its not working...it showing error element with id not found.

Comment: Are you definitively certain that `<%=rs_list_task.getString("task_id")%>` is returning non-empty?

Comment: yes..Its returning a value.